# Firefox tabs - disable auto reload page on focus tab

Tags: firefox, keyboard

I prefere the **keyboard** for surfing in Firefox 20.0 and I use Shift + Page Up (Shift + Page down) to switch between tabs. In my preferences I have "When Firefox start: open the tabs from last session".

Example: I start the browser, it automatically restore tabs 1, 2, 3,..., 20. from the last session. It's ok. It doesn't automatically refresh all tabs content - it's also ok, because I have setted up "don't restore tab until is selected".

**But:** If I try to move from tab 1 to tab 10, I have to go over tabs 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 - and here is the problem, because it starts to refresh the tab 2 - 9 content and I don't need it now, it takes a long time, especially if I have more tabs open.

I tried to set in about:config

```
accessibility.blockautorefresh = true,
```

but it doesn't work.

**Generally:** I need to disable all auto refreshing web pages (tab content), so it will load only the tab and if I will decide to load its content, I'll press F5, Ctrl + F5, or something like that.

Do you have any idea, how to fix that? Sorry for my English.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @hymie: Yes, thanks, I understand, but everything important works for me also with keyboard in Firefox, only this one issue not...

Answer (score 0):

Some of the versions made that: maybe around 14 – 17. But newer and earlier autoload on hover. And maybe in those it was because of some unknown mixture of addons and programs. But sure it was there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a keyboard guy: search by title: Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, type in the title of the page (it will be highlighted), and type <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score -1):

I'm probably going to get downvoted, but the answer to your question is

Use the mouse.

Seriously.  You're using a keyboard **alternate** to a mouse-driven graphical program.  The keyboard alternate has limitations.  One of them is that you can only move from any tab to the one immediately next to it.  If you want to skip over a bunch of tabs, then use the graphical input device designed for that purpose.